# Setup common authentication workflow for standalone webapp and Teams tab using that webapp

Tags: microsoft-teams, adal, adal.js

I am trying to integrate an existing ASP.NET MVC web app (domain - azurewebsites.net) within a Teams personal tab. How to setup a common user authentication workflow that works both for the webapp (used through a browser) and Teams Tab?

The webapp currently uses OWIN middleware (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp) to do AAD authentication for users.

This doesn’t work within the teams tab since the login redirect page doesn’t run within an iframe. I need the same source code to support both the standalone website and teams tab (along with authentication).

Thanks!

Comment: Teams support only Iframable pages. Please check the auth sample provide in the answer posted by me.

Comment: Thanks Nikitha for the answer. I went through the samples. One issue is that all of the solutions use JS libraries to implement authentication but our standalone website has AAD authentication implemented via a C# library. So it basically means we need to have 2  different entry points & modes of authentication based on where the request is coming in.
Are there any samples that talk about how to handle such a case?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the authentication using web app for the tab in team. Could you please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab) to add the authentication to your tab. We have three types of authentication methods, You can use any one of that. Also you can check this [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node/tree/master/src/views/tab)